# Highlight current link/tab on Ruby on Rails using CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application, I have this navigation bar and I want to highlight the current tab using CSS or jquery so I'm wondering how can I achieve this? I'm not using bootstrap tabs or jquery UI tabs.

This is my code

```
  <div class="jm_bar jm_filter">
   <%= link_to "Approved", dashboard_jobs_path(sort_by: 'Approved')%>
    <span class="separator"></span>
    <%= link_to "Awaiting", dashboard_jobs_path(sort_by: 'Awaiting') %>
    <span class="separator"></span>
    <%= link_to "Pending", dashboard_jobs_path(sort_by: 'Rejected') %>
    <span class="separator"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check out `:target` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target This psuedo-class selector will let you style an element differently when its id attribute match’s the url.

Answer (score 1):

If you still searching this? I don't think so, I'm writing an answer for RoR developers like me because I have faced this and now I have fixed.

Create a helper method

```
def tab_link(link_text, link_path)
    class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''

    content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
        link_to link_text, link_path
    end
end
```

On the view

```
<ul>
  <%= tab_link("Approved", dashboard_jobs_path(sort_by: 'Approved')) %>
  <%= tab_link("Awaiting", dashboard_jobs_path(sort_by: 'Awaiting')) %>
  <%= tab_link("Pending", dashboard_jobs_path(sort_by: 'Rejected')) %>
</ul>
```

Active class CSS

```
.active > a, 
.active > a:focus, 
.active > a:hover {
    border-color: #1558e7;
    background-color: #1558e7;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Now your tab link looks like this

[image]